# How to find the weekday from the date for an entire column of dates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know that you can use the DATEPART(), FORMAT(), WEEKDAY() functions to find the weekday of a single date, but I need to use these functions to create a new column that finds the weekday for an entire column of dates in date_dim_id. How do I do this?

Below is my date_dim_id column. I want to add a column beside it that tells me which weekday each date is.

[image: 1]

Comment: Seems like you are storing dates as numeric values. I strongly recommend you use the `DATE` date type instead.

Comment: Not `VARCHAR`, but `DATE`, as described in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

Comment: cast(cast(e.date_dim_id as varchar(8)) as date)
Will this line work? It returns the integer date as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Add a column and use `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select date_part(dow, '20210805') as dayoftheweek
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).